# Two "identical" projects - one adds a -90 rotation to an object on creating FBX, but the other does not. Why? Is this a bug?

Tags: mesh, unity, .fbx, empty

I am attempting to create FBX files from a Blender project for game development. However, I have encountered an irregular behavior I cannot explain and it is causing problems. I am not clear if this is a bug or there is something I am missing.

Direct blend files:

- https://blend-exchange.com/b/yMppynAG
- https://blend-exchange.com/b/kEBxAbm2

Above are two .blend files - one titled "working" and one titled "broken". Both blend files contain only a very simple hierarchy of an empty root axis with a 90 degree X-axis rotation and 8 branches of a simple tree as children. There are no rotations on any of the 8 branch children of the empty axis in either:

[image]

As far as I can tell, these two .blend files are "identical" except they were made by two different people. In both, the root axis has a 90 x-rotation, but all children objects have 0 rotations.

If you export an FBX from each .blend file, you get different behavior though. Export process in both cases:

- Right click the Empty Axis and Select Hierarchy
- File > Export FBX
- Object Types: Empty & Mesh
- Apply Scalings: FBX Units
- Forward: Y forward
- Up: Z up
- Uncheck Apply Unit, Uncheck Use Space Transform, Uncheck Apply Transform

If you then re-import the FBX's that are made you will then see that the "bark" object from the "broken" version now has a -90 rotation. However, in the FBX from the "working" version there is no such added -90 rotation to the "bark" object under "Transform".

Here you can see the added -90 rotation that is added to the "bark" object when the "broken" FBX is imported. The tree looks the same but now this object has -90 on its transform. The same does not occur with the "working" FBX:

[image]

Here is the "working" FBX when it is imported showing no rotation on this "bark" object:

[image]

Is this likely a bug to be reported or is there some possible explanation for the difference I am missing? Does this behavior reproduce on your end also or make sense in any way?

Thanks for any help or clarification.

***EDIT: BUG REPORT MADE HERE:*** https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/107915

Comment: They are not identical .blends.  One .blend is rotated 180 degrees from the other (applied.)

Comment: Fair enough Nathan. That's why I said "identical." There obviously must be some difference. But I don't think that explains the issue as that rotation is applied already. It still doesn't make sense to me that exporting to FBX is adding a visible -90 x-rotation on one and not the other from the same export/import process. In theory these could be completely different projects with different objects/meshes. We still shouldn't see this different behavior that I am aware of. Unless there is some way to see why it is happening and prevent it or at least make it consistent. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, well you should try with actually identical .blends.  Personally, I'm not interested, because I have significant doubts about the good faith of this question.

Comment: Okay Nathan. This thread is the culmination of days of trouble shooting on the Unity forum for an asset for tree importing. I did not make the "working" one - someone on the forum did. I don't know why theirs works and mine doesn't. But it is clearly abnormal that the same hierarchies would create an extra x-rotation of -90 on one and not the other, regardless of the meshes in each object. I am not sure what "good faith of the question" means. I need to import many objects into Unity and can't have random -90 unapplied rotations added in an inconsistent fashion. It breaks Unity functions.

Comment: This is the simplest I have been able to narrow the issue down in an easy comparison of two blender files, each with only 9 objects (1 empty, 8 meshes). The hierarchy and rotations of the objects before exporting/importing should be what matters. If the hierarchy is identical and every object has identical settings, the same result should happen both times. But it does not.

Comment: For the record, I just submitted a Blender bug report. In doing so I fixed the 180 rotation issue Nathan mentioned and combined the two hierarchies into one Blend project. The issue persists. The two hierarchies behave differently despite now being completely identical to the naked eye. I presume it must be a bug.